# Serialization for Java Calendar

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, fasterxml

How do I create a custom serialization for java Calendar to json by extending json `serializer<Calendar>`?

I tried the same for `java.until.Date` and it's working. In the serialization method, I converted Date as String and write it in json format.

The sample code done for java.util.Date is similar to code given below

```
  public class CDJsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{
  @Override
  public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,SerializerProvider provider)
 throws IOException {

      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
     jsonGenerator.writeString(dateString);
 }
}
```

And it is used like so:

```
 @JsonSerialize(using = CDJsonDateSerializer.class)
 private Date startDate;
```

What can I do for Serialize Calendar in java to json without losing data in Calendar object ?

Comment: Can you post your code. It will be easier to answer if we have something to start with.

Comment: I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: And what happened if you use it for Calendar?

Comment: if i follow above approach.how will i deserialize back  actual Calendar object from string written as json.?

For Date to string and viceverca. we have" format and parse "  methods

Comment: You can parse it to date and then initialize `Calendar` with it like this `c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(date);`. There is `JsonDeserializer` class for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### From JSON to [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Create a [`JsonSerializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html):

```
public class CalendarSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Calendar> {

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Calendar calendar, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        String dateAsString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        jsonGenerator.writeString(dateAsString);

    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CalendarSerializer.class)
private Calendar calendar;
```

### From [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to JSON

Create a [`JsonDeserializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html):

```
public class CalendarDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Calendar> {

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    @Override
    public Calendar deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                                DeserializationContext deserializationContext) 
                                throws IOException {

        String dateAsString = jsonParser.getText();

        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(dateAsString);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            return calendar;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
```

And then use it:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CalendarDeserializer.class)
private Calendar calendar;
```

Comment: You can set the timezone for a Calendar object, but getting a Date object from it using the getTime() method will return a Date object with the host computer's time zone. How to hanle that?Thank you

Comment: Is there any issue in handling timezone with this approach ?

Comment: @AdarshGangaprakashUnnithan You can add the timezone to your date format if you need. You can use the [ISO 8601](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/1426227) format.

Comment: If you stick to the ISO 8601 format, you can use javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If the only data you need as json is a date, you can using Gson:

```
JsonObject albums = new JsonObject();

albums.addProperty("date", new Date());
```

if your json instead has more than that, you can sonsider to define your own class and serialze it by adding this method to the defined class:

```
public String toJson() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
```

Comment: I'm able to do the same using fasterxml by converting java Date to string and write it as json. I don't know how to achieve the same for java Calendar object

Comment: @AdarshGangaprakashUnnithan, tell me  how does the output should look like?

Comment: I have updated the question with more info.In output i should be able to deserialize back the stored json object to java Calendar

Comment: @AdarshGangaprakashUnnithan you are almost there, but add as a comment to your question, how does the json with a calendar object must look like?
**{"???":"????", "???":"????", "???":"????"}**

Comment: Now im getting " unrecognized field" error while trying to seralize.so i dnt have the exact json structure for java Calendar field